# MySQLRoleProvider

Tags: asp.net, mysql, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I am using MySQL Connector/.NET and a custom MySQL membership provider.

Here is a part of the web.config:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MySQLRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add applicationName="name" description=""
      connectionStringName="MySQLMP" writeExceptionsToEventLog="False"
      autogenerateschema="True" name="MySQLRoleProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<membership defaultProvider="MySQLMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <remove name="MySQLMembershipProvider" />
    <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" applicationName="name" description="MySQL default application" connectionStringName="MySQLMP" writeExceptionsToEventLog="False" autogenerateschema="True" enablePasswordRetrieval="False" enablePasswordReset="True" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="True" requiresUniqueEmail="True" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<profile defaultProvider="MySQLProfileProvider">
  <properties>
    <add name="AccountNumber" type="string" provider="" />
    <remove name="MySQLProfileProvider" />
    <add name="MySQLProfileProvider" type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
  </properties>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="MySQLProfileProvider" connectionStringName="MySQLMP" applicationName="name" type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D" />
  </providers>
</profile>
```

In addition to that I am using ASP.NET authentication form.
What I am trying to do is: after a user logs in, I want to check if he/she is an admin and redirect to a certain page. Easy, right?

I believe, I am supposed to use the following:

```
if(Role.IsUserInRole(lgnCustomer.UserName, "Administrator"))
        lgnCustomer.DestinationPageUrl = "~/admin";
```

However, for some reason I cannot use "Role". It seems like its missing reference to the MySQLRoleProvider.

Everything else (user registration, log in, role differentiation) works...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is not as difficult as I thought.
Apparently, it does not matter that a membership provider is something other than default SQL provider. I had to use `using System.Web.Security;` in the beginning, not the `using MySQL.Web.Security;`